# Outlier removal, extremes on both ends

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, outliers

A list of numbers and I want to remove the extremes on both ends.

The standard deviation is calculated: 26.3 (rounded to 1 decimal)

```
Originals
[1.1,87.8,97.2,6.8,8.1,10.8,4.9,8.1,1.9,2.8,1.2,1.2,8.7,5.8,2.1,1.9,1.4,1.2,6.6,1.4,1.3,1.5]

Each Original v.s. Standard deviation
[0.04,3.34,3.7,0.26,0.31,0.41,0.19,0.31,0.07,0.11,0.05,0.05,0.33,0.22,0.08,0.07,0.05,0.05,0.25,0.05,0.05,0.06]
```

For this case, I want to define the numbers of below criteria as outlier:

1. either greater than 3 times of standard deviation
2. or small than 0.05 times of standard deviation

[image]

Is this a reasonable way to consider and define outlier?

(This proposed method will be applied to lists of numbers may/not normally distributed.)

Thank you.

Comment: (1) Possible that **_no_** outliers should be removed. They may give important info about what's happening. (2) I think it's a bad idea to use SD for outlier ID because SD itself is heavily influenced by outliers. (Maybe OK to check each observations by some SD method, provided that observation is removed before SD is calculated. (3) Boxplot outliers use IQR = Q3 - Q1 to measure variability; IQR is relatively robust against outliers, so that method may generally be better. (4) Why remove outliers? Obvious data entry error? Eqpt failure? Or they just annoy you?

Comment: @BruceET, thank you for details. (3) is a brilliant point. (2) is a teaching to me. for (4), there're suspicious data entry errors (not able to trace root cause) so I want to conduct outlier removal.

Comment: Data analysis needs to know more than that you have "a list of numbers". Two values look higher on any graph worthwhile, but what you do know of their context if anything?  The two values are close to 100 and the others are much closer to 0; are they percents and if not what could high values be?

Comment: @Nick Cox, thank you for the comment. This sample is taken from a case, where human entry error and misuse of input happened.

Comment: I believe you but that doesn't really impart much flavour here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Graphical comment.* If I've correctly captured your data, here is the boxplot from R. Your title says 'both ends', but I see boxplot 'outliers' only in the upper tail. Do you have any explanation how they might have arisen.

```
boxplot(x, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=19)
```

[image]

Only two 'outliers' (no tied ones).

```
length(boxplot.stats(x)$out)
[1] 2
```

Even small samples from an exponential distribution often show 'outliers'
in the right tail, which are a natural 'feature' of exponential distributions.
Would be a mistake to remove them from the sample. The population SD below is $\sigma=12.$ The SD of all 22 observations is about 11.4 (already a slight
underestimate of $\sigma.$ The SD of the 20 'non-outliers' is only about 5.2 (serious underestimate).

```
set.seed(123)
y = rexp(22, 1/12)
boxplot(y, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=19 )
sd(y)
[1] 11.38477
sd(sort(y)[1:20])
[1] 5.205213
```

[image]

For example, certain members of the Weibull family of distributions and  members of the
Pareto family have even heavier right tails, hence more 'outliers' on the
high side.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The question was about to find a way also suitable for other lists, where extremely small numbers are in. for example, [0.01,0.005,2,15,12,6.8,8.1,10.8,4.9,8.1,7,2.8]

Comment: Based on my experience, it seems to me you're altogether too willing to remove 'outliers'. Saying you have data entry errors and you're unable to find the cause seems self-contradictory. If you're talking about the equivalent of a man 12' (4m) tall, then _that's_ an outlier I'd remove. Not familiar with your data, so don't want to judge. Or if the dataset says an IQ score is 191 and the actual test paper has 91 written on it. But don't expect even honest real data to be 'tidy'--like the data in many elementary textbooks.)

Answer (score 1):

Outliers are generally defined as:

- values lower than Q1 - (1.5 * IQR) on the lower end
- values higher than Q3 + (1.5 * IQR) on the top end

More detail here: https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/3/3.2

Comment: thank you for your help to the question. Hope you don't mind I choose another which provide more details to the topic. :)

Comment: Not a problem at all.

Comment: More wrong than right, I'd say, for a bundle of reasons. (1) Outliers might exist in many different spaces (different dimensions -- univariate, bivariate, multivariate --, categorical data too, etc.) so on that ground alone this is hardly general. (2) Precise rules of thumb for outliers miss the main point, which is that identifying outliers requires background knowledge and a statistical sense of what is expected. One size fits all criteria mislead more than they help. (3) This is a perversion of the original intent in Tukey's work, at most a criterion for flagging data points to think about.

Comment: (4) "generally defined" depends on a literature survey, and it's my reading against yours, but I wouldn't summarize general statistical advice in this way. Much better advice in the question and comments of @BruceET.